# How to set As Lower Brightness as in Clock application, without rooting

Tags: screen-brightness

I noticed that with the Froyo "desk clock" application, when you put it in low light mode, it forces the back-light far darker than you can manually make it in the settings.

My question is: is there an application or a non-root hack that can make the back-light really dim just like in the desk clock application?
As that clock can set brightness lower without rooting, there should be a way to do that without rooting.

Comment: I don't know anything about the particulars of this situation, but I'd just like to point out that just because a system app can do something does not mean that other non-root apps can. Apps signed with the system-keys have access to far more permissions and APIs than other apps, enabling manufacturers to do many more things than a typical 3rd party developer. For example, some phones can take screenshots with a simple key combination, but you need root to accomplish this from a 3rd party app.

Comment: I just noticed this same thing last night when I was setting my clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clock app is setting flags on its own fullscreen window that override the system default screen brightness, but this only affects that app's window.

See the [source for DeskClock.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/deskclock/DeskClock.java;h=7460e7ddff3e75d7ef69d9c55e5cd997799bc5f2;hb=HEAD)

```
 551             winParams.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
 552             winParams.dimAmount = DIM_BEHIND_AMOUNT_DIMMED;
 553             winParams.buttonBrightness = WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF;
```

The flags used are documented on the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#buttonBrightness), in particular:

> float BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_OFF Value
>   for screenBrightness and
>   buttonBrightness indicating that the
>   screen or button backlight brightness
>   should be set to the lowest value when
>   this window is in front.

So, the DeskClock is not using anything special to dim the screen, but it can only affect its own window.

Comment: Does it mean that low brightness of clock has no effect on battery? I mean lower battery usage

Comment: According to the accepted answer for [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/do-bright-wallpapers-spend-more-battery-than-dark-ones), it will help battery usage for OLED, AMOLED, and Super AMOLED, but not LCD screens.

Comment: Does that code indicate that an application with such ability (dim beyond original limit for all apps) can be built?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Screen Filter](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.haxor).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read books in low light, use Foxit Reader, it can dim the screen nearly as clock.