# Power Saving Option in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life

I see there is a **Power Saving** switch in the **Galaxy S3**.

What makes the Galaxy S3 save power when it is turned on?

Is there a difference this and using **JuiceDefender**?

Can using **JuiceDefender** and turning on the **Power Saving** switch help or hinder performance?

Comment: Please avoid placing several question onto the same post. Provided answers get hard to be accurate or complete as to satisfy the multiple topics presented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, Samsung's Power Saving Mode consists of 4 features:

- CPU Power Saving: Limits the maximum performance of the processor (may also disable some cores).
- Screen Power Saving: Uses a low power level for the screen.
- Background Color: Uses a dark background color for some apps, which might reduce power consumption on some screens (see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/do-bright-wallpapers-spend-more-battery-than-dark-ones)).
- Turn off haptic feedback: It's the vibrating if you use the hardware keys or type something on the virtual keyboard.

[JuiceDefender](http://www.juicedefender.com/#features) consists of several other features which might save some battery, if correctly configured:

- It lets you control when to use WLAN/2G/3G connection, so you don't need to change them manually (It can be configured to disable all 3G and WLAN at night for example).
- It has location aware WLAN control, so it can automatically enable/disable WLAN when it's available in this location.
- It can also do CPU-Scaling, limiting your CPU power when your phone is in idle state.

  * Some features might not work because they need a specific ROM.

So JuiceDefender can save a lot of battery life if properly configured and will only slow down your phone when it's not in use (only if configured properly). (CPU) Power Saving will definitely reduce your performance.

Comment: tasker or llama can also automate your wifi / 3g connections based on location as well as switching profiles etc.

Comment: Keep in mind tools like JuiceDefender might also cause a lot of wake locks and can also drain your battery a lot. More about wake locks: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809