# Is there a grayscale mode for the Samsung Galaxy S5 (and other Samsung phones) on Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung

The Marshmallow update for Samsung phones (mine is a Galaxy S5, but the Note series has the same problem) seems to have removed the ability to turn on grayscale mode when activating power saver mode.

Is there a way to re-enable this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Samsung removed the feature from Power Saving, but you can still activate grayscale mode in the developer options.

Go to your Settings and into the Developer Options.

- If developer options isn't there, you have to manually activate the feature. Follow the steps in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33497/11190).

Scroll to the `Hardware-accelerated rendering` section, and click on `Simulate color space`. Then select `Monochromacy`. Your phone is now in grayscale mode.

This color space option also exists on other phones.

Comment: I'm not sure if this brings anything in terms of power saving (most probably the reason why Samsung removed it in the first place), but the same menu also offer option allowing to simulate color blindness, thanks for the information!

Comment: The screen on the S5 is AMOLED, so I imagine it has a little power saving effect. But I don't know for sure. But I do prefer grayscale at night, since it seems easier on the eyes.

Comment: I suppose that power efficiency is more a matter of luminosity than color, and that grey scale produces the same level of luminosity than colors ([possibly related topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5043/107603)). By the way, there are apps which use a filter to adapt the color temperature according to the time of the day, and CyanogenMod features a "LiveDisplay" option to automatically adjust color temperature and luminosity according to time and ambient luminosity.